# Как добавить новый текст в пересылаемом сообщении telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Чтобы переслать сообщение нужно использовать  bot.forward_message, но как указать при этом еще свое сообщение, учитывая  что bot.forward_message принимает TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id